# Prompt user to download .html page generated from .aspx

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, download

I have a default page with a button that prompts user to download a "signature"

Which is basically an .html file with specific format (based on user info)

So currently I have an .aspx page but I'm not sure how to make the user download the "rendered HTML page from that aspx"

On the default page i have the following

```
   Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Response.ContentType = "text/html"
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=My_Signature.html")
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Signature.aspx"))
        Response.End()

    End Sub
```

Is it possible to render the aspx page in the background then somehow  prompt the user to download it ( the resulted html) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making it more difficult than it is. Simply download the file content as you would from any other website, store it in a string, write it to the response.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Response.ContentType = "text/html"
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=My_Signature.html")
        Dim contents As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + ResolveUrl("~/Signature.aspx"))    
        Response.Write(contents)
        Response.End()    
    End Sub
```

Of course, a better solution would be to put your code for generating the signature in a Class Library (.dll) and then call that as needed.

Comment: Using your code it will still generate some aspx code like ï»¿<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Signature.aspx.vb" Inherits="Signature" %>  in the header and so on. I don't think the downloaded version is fully rendered html

Comment: You'll have to figure out why that error happened. Check the Windows Event Logs on the server.

Comment: I would love to mason but can't find such option

Answer (score 2):

You could override the Render() method of the aspx file so it writes an html file:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
    Dim hwriter As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    MyBase.Render(hwriter)
    Using outfile As New StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(".") + "\signature.html")
        outfile.Write(sb.ToString())
    End Using
    Response.ContentType = "text/html"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;   filename=signature.html")
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/signature.html"))
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

All this would be in the aspx file to be converted to html (signature.aspx). I would say have your button click do a redirect to a new window that calls the aspx, and thus this method.

Comment: I'm unable to make it work it say missing signature.html file

Comment: Could you elaborate? What line does it throw the error on/what's the error message? You might have to extend your StreamWriter file path to include the full directory.

Comment: try with this line: `Using outfile As New StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(".") + "\signature.html")`

Comment: If you follow this method, you'll be left with a file on your server and you could also run into issues if multiple people are accessing that file at once. That's a bad idea. There's no need to write it to a file beforehand, just store it in a string and then write the string to the response.

Comment: That's a valid point, i'll admit I didn't think of your method!

Comment: Your method of rendering the page's HTML is fine, it's just that there's no need to create a file and it leads to unnecessary complications. I suggest revamping it a slight bit to do `Response.Write(sb.ToString())` instead of `Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/signature.html")` and removing the code that created `outfile`.

Comment: That would work, but I think getting the string equivalent within his button handler without having to override the aspx's Render() method is a cleaner option.